# Fazer item ficar aberto ao dar hover

Tags: css

Boa tarde, tenho um "menu" e ao invés de estar um item dentro do outro, estou usando o ~ para poder dar hover no elemento posterior ao que passei o mouse, então, esse elemento abre, só que assim, como ele não está "dentro", ao tirar o mouse do elemento que recebe o efeito de hover, esse elemento posterior fecha.

Vou dar um exemplo simples:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin: 15px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 2px blue;
}

.sss {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 2px red;
  display: none;
}

a:hover ~ span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu</a>
          <span class="sss">Meu primeiro link</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu</a>
          <span class="sss">Meu segundo link</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Como podem ver, o elemento span até aparece, mas se eu tiro o mouse do elemento li, esse elemento span some, eu preciso deixar ele aberto...

Comment: Você basicamente se respondeu na pergunta. Se quer que o efeito `hover` se mantenha, você precisa que o elemento a ser exibido esteja dentro do próprio elemento. Por exemplo, por que não fazer `li:hover > span`?

Comment: Anderson, obrigado, mas na verdade preciso que se mantenha mesmo não estando dentro, seria possível? Pois como esse "menu" eu não posso mexer na estrutura dele (plataforma SaaS), teria que fazer algo nesse sentido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você mesmo respondeu: o problema se dá porque são elementos irmãos; quando o *mouse* está sobre o menu secundário, o evento de *hover* é encerado. Como resolver? Fazer que o `hover` permaneça mesmo sobre o menu secundário. Por exemplo, por quê não utilizar o `li:hover`?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin: 15px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 2px blue;
}

.sss {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 2px red;
  display: none;
}

li:hover>span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
    <span class="sss">Meu primeiro link</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
    <span class="sss">Meu segundo link</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Melhorando a resposta:**
Como na resposta do Anderson Carlos Woss, você tem que colocar o hover em uma tag acima para funcionar, no seu caso no `<li>`

Neste exemplo que citei a classe dropdown está acima de dropdown-content

foco no trecho:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

Eu achei este exemplo, creio que vai te ajudar.
Fonte:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Exemplo Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Mova o mouse acima do botão para exibir os menus</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funciona neste exemplo porque a classe .dropdown está acima de .dropdown-content.
No exemplo dele a tag <a> está no mesmo nível que a tag <span>, teria que usar o hover no <li>.

Basicamente é a mesma coisa que você falou acima.

Answer (score 2):

Consigo imaginar duas alternativas,

1. Grudar o menu e submenu e colocar o `display: block` no *hover* do elemento `span` também:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin: 15px 15px 0 15px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 2px blue;
}

.sss {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 2px red;
  display: none;
}

a:hover ~ span {
  display: block;
}
span:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
    <span class="sss">Meu primeiro link</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
    <span class="sss">Meu segundo link</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

2. Adicionar a mudança de `display` no *hover* do elemento pai, no caso, o `<li>`:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin: 15px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 2px blue;
}

.sss {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 2px red;
  display: none;
}

li:hover > span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
    <span class="sss">Meu primeiro link</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu</a>
    <span class="sss">Meu segundo link</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

É possível fazer com animações mas é muito trabalho desnecessário